# Dudas sobre error de sintaxis

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Me sale este error al hacer un proceso en mi sistema:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1,
>   query was: SELECT `movimientosformatos`.* FROM `movimientosformatos`
>   WHERE (idMovimiento=)

¿Alguien nota algo mal en la siguiente sintaxis?

```
if($file["idSalaColaborativa"] != null && $file["idSalaColaborativa"] > 0)
            {
                $select = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from("movimientos")->where("idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
                $movimientos = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);

                if(count($movimientos)>0){
                    foreach($movimientos as $movimiento){
                        $this->getAdapter()->delete("movimientosformatos","idMovimiento={$movimiento["idMovimiento"]}");
                    }
                }

                $this->getAdapter()->delete("movimientos", "idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
                $this->getAdapter()->delete("salascolaborativas", "idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
            }
```

Comment: Tienes un fallo en la query, en la clausula idMovimiento no recibe ningún valor, si lees el error con atención lo veras

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$movimiento["idMovimiento"]` no está teniendo ningún valor.

El error dice claramente que tienes un error en la query: `SELECT movimientosformatos.* FROM movimientosformatos WHERE (idMovimiento=)`, y como podrás ver, la parte `(idMovimiento=)` no está completa. O sea que no estás poniendo el valor que esperabas.